# How to improve the accuracy of a Naive Bayes Classifier?

Tags: performance, hadoop, mahout, tf-idf

I am using Naive Bayes Classifier. Following this [tutorial](http://chimpler.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/using-the-mahout-naive-bayes-classifier-to-automatically-classify-twitter-messages/).
For the the trained data, i am using 308 questions and categorizing them into 26 categories which are manually tagged.
Before sending the data i am performing NLP. In NLP i am performing(punctuation removal, tokenization, stopword removal and stemming) 
This filtered data, am using as input for mahout. 
Using mahout NBC's i train this data and get the model file. Now when i run

```
mahout testnb
```

command i get Correctly Classified Instances as 96%.

Now for my test data i am using 100 questions which i have manually tagged. And when i use the trained model with the test data, i get Correctly Classified Instances as 1%.
This is pissing me off.

Can anyone suggest me what i doing wrong or suggest me some ways to increase the performance of NBC.?

Also, ideally how much of questions data should i use to train and test?

Comment: You have 300 tagged input "vectors" for training? Are you serious?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut is 300 too less? How many questions should we ideally train for each class/category?

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be the classic problem of ["overfitting"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting)... where you get a very high % accuracy on the training set, but a low % in real situations.

You probably need more training instances. Also, there is the possibility that the 26 categories don't correlate to the features you have. Machine Learning isn't magical and needs some sort of statistical relationship between the variables and the outcomes. Effectively, what NBC might be doing here is effectively "memorizing" the training set, which is completely useless for questions outside of memory.

Comment: i have increased the trained dataset to 600, the test dataset to 100, reduced the categories and now its 8 categories. And got the accuracy of 17% on the test data without NLP.

And with NLP, i get accuracy of 10%.

In NLP performing (punctuation removal, stopword removal, tokenization and stemming)

Please suggest me some advice. Can't figure out what i am doing wrong. Should i use NLP? and also how much should i increase the trained and test data?

Comment: @user2331441 I believe you are doing no wrong, its a statistical problem, lets say in categories you have trained 80 (10 for each category) then future sentences in your test set must have some related/similar words.

for example if question, 'what colour is the sun?' and you have trained the answer for 'the sun is yellow'. then if future questions don't contain the word 'colour' and 'sun' then you wont get a hit on your answer, so if someone inputs the question 'what shade  is the star that the earth orbits?' there is no correlation between your trained data, and the question just asked ...

Comment: The more data you train, the more accuracy you will have ... (the larger the body of text, the more likely you will get hits, but also the more likely you will get false positives) ... this is just my experience so far however!